# How to initialize a set and print an empty set {} in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried `x={}` but this gives a dict

I also tried `x=set()` but when I do print(x) it gives output as `set()` and not `{}`

How do I initialize and print a set such that if it is empty then it should show {} and not set()

Example: If the set has contents, then it gets printed as `{1,2,3}` but if empty then I want it to show as `{}` (and not as `set()`). Does this need to be done programmatically using if len(x) = 0: then x='{}' else x ? Or is there any other approach to print an empty set as {} ?

Comment: `set()` is an empty set. `{}` is an empty dictionary.

Comment: `set()` is correct. It is printed as `set()` instead of `{}` to distinguish it from a dict. If you want to print `{}`, then use `print("{}")`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`set()` is correct. It is printed as `set()` instead of `{}` to distinguish it from a dict.

A short way to print a set as `{}` if it is empty might be something like this:

```
x = set()
print(x or '{}')
```

Thus:

```
>>> x = set()
>>> print(x or '{}')
{}
>>> x.add(5)
>>> print(x or '{}')
{5}
```